# \u00a0 becomes Â in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, string

I have a string that contains a lot of `\u00a0`s and I want to store that one in my database.

Everything is fine, but as soon as I put the string into my database, the `\u00a0` are shown as a `Â` and a space. The charset is UTF8. Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Since the charset is set to UTF8 in phpMyAdmin, it shouldn't be a display issue.

When I export the table, the weird symbol stays there.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the literal `\u00a0`? Just escape the \, as in `\\u00a0`.

Comment: "shown" where, exactly?  This is more likely a presentation issue in whatever client is displaying the data than in the storage in the table itself.

Comment: Shown in PhpMyAdmin and I want the empty space displayed which gets displayed just fine, but with that weird symbol in front.

Comment: the empty space you're seeing is the `\00` - the accented 'A' is the `\a0` being shown in some other charset (probably ISO-8859-1)

Comment: `\u00a0` is, among other things, a JavaScript character reference but it doesn't have any meaning in SQL or MySQL.